# Javascript How to Click on Element have preventDefault

Tags: javascript, click

I am writing javascript auto click element on other site but this site have html with jsaction,preventDefault,... and my code doesnt work.

```
<content class="z80M1" jsaction="click:o6ZaF(preventDefault=true); mousedown:lAhnzb; mouseup:Osgxgf; mouseenter:SKyDAe; mouseleave:xq3APb; touchstart:jJiBRc; touchmove:kZeBdd; touchend:VfAz8(preventMouseEvents=true)" jsname="j7LFlb" aria-label="Tùy chọn" role="menuitem" tabindex="-1"><div class="aBBjbd MbhUzd" jsname="ksKsZd"></div><div class="uyYuVb oJeWuf" jsaction="JIbuQc:moOekf" jslog="9456; track:JIbuQc"><div class="jO7h3c">Option</div></div></content>
```

My code:

```
var elem = document.querySelectorAll('content[class="z80M1"]')[0];
elem.click();
```

I want click on this, someone can help me plz.

Answer (score 0):

I think you don't target the right element or in the right way.

```js
let el = document.querySelector('#click')
let fn = (e) => {
 e.preventDefault()
 alert('click')
}

el.addEventListener('click', fn)
el.click()
```

```html
<a href="#" id="click">test</a>
```